# Checkbox losing check after layout width change

Tags: android

I am having trouble with checkbox losing state once my layout width changes after hiding some view. See images

Without hiding the other team:

[image: Without hiding the other team]

Losing state after hiding:

[image: Losing state after hiding]

I am using linearlayout's weight for auto adjustment of my layout's width but it loses my checkbox's state.
I have tried manually re-setting it after hiding the view but it doesn't seem to work.

```
if (id == R.id.home_lv) mView.hideGuestTeamList();
else mView.hideHomeTeamList();

cbSelector.setChecked(true);
```

**Problem:** How do i retain the state after stretching my view?

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Edit: My adapter doesn't have logical operation. The view handler was inside a function that my fragment will call.

```
public void setListClickListener(ListView listView) {
    final int id = listView.getId();

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            CheckBox cbSelector = view.findViewById(R.id.player_name);

            if(mSelectedItemCount < 5 || cbSelector.isChecked()) {
                cbSelector.setChecked(!cbSelector.isChecked());

                if (cbSelector.isChecked()) mSelectedItemCount++;
                else mSelectedItemCount--;

                mView.hideProceedButton();

                switch (mSelectedItemCount) {
                    case 0:
                        mView.showHomeTeamList();
                        mView.showGuestTeamList();
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        if (id == R.id.home_lv) mView.hideGuestTeamList();
                        else mView.hideHomeTeamList();

                        cbSelector.setChecked(true);
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        mView.showProceedButton();
                        break;
                }
            }else{
                mView.showLimitMessage();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Unless you're somehow saving and restoring the checked items in your `Adapter`, that's going to happen whenever the `ListView` refreshes, not just from resizing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was really in my adapter. All i did was to check my view and return it if it isnt null.

```
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    if(convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(layoutId, parent, false);

        if (layoutId == R.layout.team_list_item) {
            CircleImageView civ = convertView.findViewById(R.id.player_image);
            CheckBox name = convertView.findViewById(R.id.player_name);

            name.setText(players.get(position).getName());
        }
    }

    return convertView;
}
```